# Turbo Pascal handle Nan and INF values in floating point variable

Tags: nan, floating-point-conversion, turbo-pascal

I've got a Turbo Pascal 5.5 program which has generated a binary data file containing Not A Number values. Using Turbo Pascal 5.5, I can import the data file correctly. But when I get an range-check error when I test

```
If a.aSingle > 0 then
```

I can, of course, turn off range checking, but I still need to identify NaN and INF values and convert them to a different form.

Is there a Borland/Turbo Pascal method for identifying NaN values in Turbo Pascal 5.5? Or do I have to map the number into a LongInt and check the bit values?

Comment: Turbo Pascal...what sweet memories! It had very few mathematical functions then AFAIK yes, you have to map with `absolute` to a `LongInt` and check its raw value.

Comment: Peter Mortensen has edited "TP5.5" to "Turbo Pascal 5.5". My apologies to anyone reading this who might know anything about TP5.5, but I'm not going to change it back: I'm not going to get involved in an edit war with someone who has nothing better to do than mess up questions.